# What are the bug and fish vendor spawn conditions? (CJ and Flick)

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

CJ (fish purchaser) and Flick (bug purchaser) appear from time to time in my island town and offer better prices when selling fish/bugs.

What are their spawn conditions or do they appear randomly?

Answer (score 1):

They appear randomly. Except CJ does appear once every season for the tourney (and you can sell him some fish that you caught outside the tourney)